# Thunderbolt display fails to play audio

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, preferences, thunderbolt-display

I'm running a MacBook Pro (late 2011 model) that has a recent OS X upgrade to version 10.8.1.  For some reason, when the MacBook Pro is docked to the Thunderbolt display, it no longer sends sound out the Thunderbolt display, but instead uses the tinny MacBook Pro speakers.  I looked in Preferences to see if there is some way to get the big display to handle the sound.  Any ideas?

Comment: Run Software Update with the TB display connected, it may require a firmware update.

Comment: da4: You solved it.  I'm now at OS X v10.8.2.  All is well.

Comment: Glad to hear it, might want to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Software Update with the TB display connected, it may require a firmware update.  (edit: changed from comment to answer)

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to change my Sound Output preference to "Display Audio".

Comment: It also helps to make sure that when you select _Display Audio_ that you also check the [ ] Mute box is unchecked.

Comment: Sometimes after doing this you just need to change the volume up or down to trigger the change otherwise sound would come out of nowhere...